# CompareValidator asp.net Type:String

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to use CompareValidator witch compare the field for string.and the 
server code to write in the Label1 the result.I tried with integer and date data types and it 
work fine but when i put string its not working.When i put integer in the field it consider that is true.How to make it work.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="name" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" MaxLength="40">   </asp:TextBox>
 <asp:CompareValidator 
      ID="CompareValidator1" 
      runat="server"
       ControlToValidate="name"
       Operator="DataTypeCheck" 
       Type="String">
 </asp:CompareValidator>
 <asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="Label" Visible="True"></asp:Label>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server" Text="Изпрати"  BackColor="Black" BorderColor="Black" BorderStyle="None" ForeColor="White" OnClick="PageValidate_SendMail" />

protected void PageValidate_SendMail(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Page.IsValid) {

            Label1.Text = "String";

        }
        else {
            Label1.Text = "Integer";

        }
    }
```

Comment: `String` is the default [`Type`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basecomparevalidator.type(v=vs.110).aspx). I assume that it simply means that every type is allowed. You need a `CustomValidator` then which checks the other types and set `args.IsValid = false` if any `TryParse` check   works (e.g. `DateTime.TryParse`/`int.TryParse`).

Answer (score 2):

What you will need is RegularExpressionValidator something like below. The **ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*$** restricts input to alphabets only.

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="name" ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z]*$" ErrorMessage="RegularExpressionValidator" Display="Dynamic"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

You might want to use **RequiredFieldValidator** as well for checking empty input.

And if none of those meet your requirements then you will need to use CustomValidator.

Comment: I tried with the espression.It is okey for validating the string.But now if I type something different the only way to receive the error massage is by using ErrorMessage Property .Somehow the Else section is skipped and is overtaken by the error property.Is there a way to override ErrorMessage property with my custom label massage. The reason to to this is because i can't position the ErrorMassage it stay only to the right side .

Comment: By default Else would not even execute since the validation is done on client-side. To position the message, you can place the Validator wherever you want on the page. You can also use ValidationSummary Control: http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/ValidationSummary-Example-in-asp-net